# Salesforce Two Factor Authorization in VPN and JIRA

Tags: apex, rest-api, authentication

I want know how to do two factor authentication for VPN and JIRA in salesforce.

while I am trying to access the JIRA webservice(REST API) link from browser, I can able to see the values in JSON format. But while I am accessing the JIRA webservice from salesforce Apex code I am getting Server 503 error.

This is caused, that we are connecting the JIRA through VPN. SO I am getting the server 503 error from salesforce APEX code.

Is there any possible way to authenticate both VPN and JIRA from salesforce Apex code.

Comment: If you mean 2 way SSL (Mutual Auth) http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has less to do with the vpn, and more to do with ip address restrictions. Regardless, because two-factor auth is, in general, based around the idea of having both something you know (a password) and something you have (a token, or a rsa key, etc.) I don't know of a way to automate two-factor auth ... in fact that would kind of sidestep the point.